# Installing pygame on python 3.7.4

Tags: python, installation, pygame

I have a summer homework to learn pygame so I am trying to install it. I have already installed the latest version of python but now I do not know how to install pygame. I have tried to use different pip commands but none of the m seem to work, I don't know whether I'm using commands for an older version of python or I'm just using them wrong.
Thanks

I got the pip commands from the pygame website:

```
python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user
py -m pip install -U pygame --user
```

error messages:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
py -m pip install -U pygame --user
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Don't execute this in the interactive python shell, but in your normal terminal/cmd

Comment: Thank you, I have now installed it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be getting a syntax error on the pip install command. My guess is you're running the command in the python shell rather than the terminal. Try running it in the terminal and that should solve your problems.

Comment: Thank you, I've installed pygame now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the following command in the command prompt 
or terminal

pip install pygame

Comment: Since @mabski is using Python **3**, the command might also be `pip3`.  Under a lot of common UNIXes, python 2.7 is the default python, so just `pip` will install for python 2.7, not python 3.